# C#: Save serialized object to the text field in the DB, how maintain object format versions in the future?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, serialization, deserialization

I've complex object (nested properties, collections etc) in my ASP.NET MVC C# application. I don't need to save it into the multiple tables in the DB, serializing the whole object and store it like a whole is ok.

I plan to serialize the whole object (in something human-readable like JSON/XML) and store in text field in the DB.

I need to later load this object from the DB and render it using strongly-typed view.

Here comes the question: in the future the class of the object can change (I can add\remove fields etc). But serialized versions saved into the DB before will not reflect change.

How to deal with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write some sort of conversion utility every time you significantly change structured, serialized messages, and run it as part of an upgrade process. Adding or removing fields that are nullable isn't likely to be a problem, but larger structural changes will be.

You could do something like implement IXmlSerializable, peek at the message and figure out what version the message is and convert it appropriately, but this will quickly become a mess if you have to do this a lot and your application has a long lifecycle. So, you're better off doing it up front in an upgrade process, and outside of your application.

If you are worried about running the conversion on lots of records as part of an upgrade, you could come up with some ways to make it more efficient (for example, add a column to the table that contains the message schema version, so you can efficiently target messages that are out of date).

Answer (score 2):

As long as you're using JSON or XML, added fields shouldn't be a problem (as long as no specific version schemas are enforced), The default .net XML serializer for instance, doesn't include fields that have their default value (which can be set with the System.Component.DefaultValue attribute). So the new fields will be treated the same as the omitted fields while deserializing and get their default values (default class values that is, the DefaultValue attribute only applies to serialization/designer behaviour).
Removed fields depends on your deserialization implementation, but can be made so that those are ignored. Personally I tend to keep the properties but mark them as obsolete with a message of what they were once for. That way when coding you'll know not to use them, but can still be filled for backwards compatibility (and they shouldn't be serialized when marked obsolete). When possible you could implement logic in the obsolete property that fills the renewed data structure.